# Create recursive query SQLite3 Get parent from child

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion

Need help for creating recursive query

Exist data:

We have Offices (Type-1), Departments(Type-2) and Employees(Type-3)

[image]

Necessary to get the name of the office and all employees names of this office for the selected employee

As example: input 13 *(it's employee id)* we get output: "Офис в Москве: Винтиков, Шпунтиков, Белова, Крылова, Петрова, Иванова."

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `join`s for this purpose.  To get the number of employees in an office, you can use:

```
select td.parentid,
       sum(case when te.type = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as num_employees
from t td join
     t te
     on te.parentid = td.id
where t3.type = 3
group by td.parentid;
```

Then, you need one more `join` to get the name and a `having` clause to see if the office has a particular employee:

```
select to.id, to.name,
       sum(case when te.type = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as num_employees
from to join
     t td
     on td.parentid = to.id join
     t te
     on te.parentid = td.id
where t3.type = 3
group by to.id, to.name
having sum(case when t3.name = ? then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question on Python:

SQLite table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "row" (
  "Id"  INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  "ParentId"    REFERENCES row,
  "Name"    TEXT NOT NULL,
  "Type"    INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(Type > 0 AND Type <= 3),
PRIMARY KEY("Id"))
```

To recursively find the office by employee ID:

```
index = 13
cursor.execute(
  f"""
    SELECT * FROM row WHERE Id={index}
  """
)

selected_employee = cursor.fetchone()

cursor.execute(
  f"""
    WITH RECURSIVE
      over_employee(Id, ParentId, Name, Type, level)
      AS (
        VALUES({index}, {selected_employee[1]}, "{selected_employee[2]}", {selected_employee[3]}, 0)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT row.Id, row.ParentId, row.Name, row.Type, over_employee.level+1
        FROM row JOIN over_employee ON row.Id=over_employee.ParentId
        )
      SELECT Id, Name, Type, level FROM over_employee;
  """
)

employee_office = cursor.fetchall()[-1]
```

To recursively find out all employees of the resulting office:

```
cursor.execute(
  f"""
    WITH RECURSIVE
    under_office(Id, Name, Type, level) AS (
      VALUES({employee_office[0]}, "{employee_office[1]}", {employee_office[2]}, 0)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT row.Id, row.Name, row.Type, under_office.level+1
        FROM row JOIN under_office ON row.ParentId=under_office.Id
    )
    SELECT Name FROM under_office WHERE Type=3;
  """
)

print("Output:")
print("{}:".format(employee_office[1]), end=' ')
for res in cursor:
  print(res[0], end=', ')
```

Output:

> Офис в Москве: Винтиков, Шпунтиков, Морозов, Белова, Крылова, Иванова,
> Петрова,